# Connecting to a Remote Server for the First Time

Tags: 12.04, webserver, remote

I'd like to know how to connect to a remote Ubuntu 12.04LTS OS server. I've never done this, and wondered if anyone would be willing to help a noob out; I'd appreciate it!

I've always wanted to be able to connect to a remote machine via the terminal and even more so something that I can use to access the server in a window on my current machine (like it's own desktop).

Answer (score 3):

To connect a remote server:
Type the following command in your terminal

```
ssh remote_username@remote_host
```

which ssh is the command and is a shortend for secure shell
replace remote_username and remote_host with proper UserName and HosName

Answer (score 0):

That should be really simple:

open a terminal on your local system.

Type

```
 ssh yournick@address.of.remote.system
```

You will be asked to provide you password. After entering it, you should be connected.

It may be possible, that the remote machine is behind a firewall. in that case you will have to configure the firewall so it lets the connection through.

Comment: Don't forget to install ```openssh``` on your server before trying to connect to it.

Comment: you will need openssh on both, the server and the connecting machine.

Comment: btw, if your remote machine does not have a (known) name ("address"), you may want to connect by ip address. If you have access to the machine you can get the ip by entering
    'ip a'
If your remote is a virtual server, you should have gotten the address by your provider.

Comment: I was able to connect to the server via terminal (I'm stoked, thank you). Now I'm attempting to connect via VNC; it doesn't appear to want to do anything but tell me it's "Connecting". I do have the IP, and login details-but no cigar quite yet (using Screen Sharing app on Mac OS X). I discovered that my host has SSH installed, and that I as a Mac user also have it installed by default. Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

To use a graphical connection, here is a good writeup.

http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-use-remote-desktop-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you, however if I'm not mistaken that is for someone already with a graphical interface-I'm on a Mac machine trying to gain a graphical interface of a remote server.

Comment: I'm Mac clueless, but I use a VNC client from windows to remote desktop into my Ubuntu boxes.  So if there is a Mac VNC client, give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer to connect without the terminal,
Go to Ubuntu Home Directory > Other Locations
Then type,

```
ssh://remote_username@remote_host
```

Press enter, Type password when prompted.
Now you're done =)